# Are there any javascript libs to pixel compare images using HTML5 canvas (or any other means)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Would like to test if 2 images pixel match and/or whether a smaller sized image pixel matches some same sized section of a larger image.

Comment: Egad, in the browser? Please tell me your site so I can not go there and not lock up my browser :)

Comment: Friend asked who's building internal tool for a QA team.  Thought it sounded interesting :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first part, test if two images match perfectly, is pretty straight forward.

```
//assuming data1,data2 are canvas data of images of the same size
function isMatch(data1,data2){
    for(var i = 0; i<data1.length; i++){
        if(data1[i] != data2[i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As long as you aren't using extremely hi-res images I wouldn't worry about speed, one iteration trough canvas data like this is typically very fast, ~10ms per Mega Pixel on a decent computer with a modern browser.  Remember width and height of the images must be the same.  For most practical purposes this yes or no match is not very useful, encoding errors lead to imperceptible changes in images, it is best to use a metric to measure how far apart the two images are.  A naive but fairly effective metric is the [RMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of the two images:

```
//assuming data1,data2 are canvas data of images of the same size
function rmsDiff(data1,data2){
    var squares = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<data1.length; i++){
        squares += (data1[i]-data2[i])*(data1[i]-data2[i]);
    }
    var rms = Math.sqrt(squares/data1.length);
    return rms;
}
```

Here the rms will range from [0,255], 0 if the images match exactly, 255 if one image is all rgba(0,0,0,0) and the other is all rgba(255,255,255,255).  How to threshold what is an acceptable rms difference is up to you to tune (around 1 to 2 perhaps).

For the second part of your question, whether a smaller sized image pixel matches some same sized section of a larger image, I'm assuming that they are not translated and that we know the scale difference between the two, otherwise this would open it up into a very complicated and interesting problem see [Pattern Recognition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition).  Then with this egregious assumption I would use the canvas to scale the large image down to the exact same size as the smaller one and get the rms between them.  Don't test for an exact match as scaling will always create slight errors and never be an exact match.

Comment: It should be noted that unfortunately even exactly-the-same image will have different pixel values when turned to an image, and turned to canvas.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is anything like that out there, and I'm not sure the web-browser is the place to do it in... however I have been playing around with the canvas element a little bit and wanted to share what I come up with. Maybe you find something useful in it.

The code below is tested in Chrome 20 only.
**You must have the images and the script loaded from the same domain**, or it will not work (I didn't find a way to upload images on jsfiddle so I didn't put this there)

To test if two images are identical I load each image and draw it on a canvas element, and compare the width, height and pixeldata.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="compare.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Identical pixels
compare.js

```
$(function(){
  function compare(url_a, url_b, callback) {
    var canvas = $("<canvas>").appendTo(document.body)[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var
      image_a = new Image(),
      image_b = new Image();

    function getData(image) {
      //Set canvas to the same size as the image
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      //Draw the image on the canvas
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
      //Get the image data from the canvas.
      return ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }

    function compareIdentical(A,B) {
      // Check sizes
      if (
        A.width != B.width ||
        A.height != B.height ||
        A.data.length != B.data.length
      ) {
        return callback(false,'Not same size');
      }
      var a=A.data; b=B.data;
      //Check image data
      for (var idx=0, len=A.data.length; idx < len; ++idx) {
        if (a[idx] !== b[idx]) {
          return callback(false,'Not same');
        }
      }
      return callback(true,'Identical');
    }

    $(image_a).load(function(){
      console.log('Image A loaded');
      image_a = getData(image_a);
      //Load image b
      image_b.src = url_b;
    });

    $(image_b).load(function(){
      console.log('Image B loaded');
      image_b = getData(image_b);
      canvas.parentNode.removeChild(canvas);
      compareIndentical(image_a, image_b);
      //comparePartOf(image_a, image_b);
    });

    //Load image a
    image_a.src = url_a;
  }

  //IMPORTANT: Images must be loaded from the same domain as the
  //script, or getImageData will not give any data.
  compare(
    'IMG_2195.JPG',
    'IMG_2195.JPG',
    function(result,message){
      console.log(result,message);
    }
  );

});
```

To test if an image is part of another image, **is slow**.

- Compare sizes: if SMALL > BIG then it can't be part of BIG.
- For every x and y of BIG, compare if SMALL is a fit.

(add this to the code above, and change the call after image B is loaded)

```
    function comparePartOf(bigimg, smallimg) {
      if (
        bigimg.width < smallimg.width ||
        bigimg.height < smallimg.height ||
        bigimg.data.length < smallimg.data.length
      ) {
        return callback(false,'bigimg smaller than smallimg');
      }

      var
        big=bigimg.data,
        small=smallimg.data,
        idx,
        len=small.length/4,
        big_x,
        big_y,
        big_width = bigimg.width,
        big_height = bigimg.height,
        small_x,
        small_y,
        small_width = smallimg.width,
        small_height = smallimg.height,
        lenw = big_width - small_width,
        lenh = big_height - small_height,
        big_offset,
        small_offset,
        result=false;

      for(big_x=0; big_x < lenw; ++big_x) {
        for(big_y=0; big_y < lenh; ++big_y) {
          result = true;
          for (idx=0; idx < len; ++idx) {
            small_x = idx % small_width;
            small_y = Math.floor(idx / small_width);
            big_offset = (
              (big_x + small_x) + ((big_y + small_y) * big_width)
            )<<2;
            small_offset = idx << 2;
            if (
              big[big_offset++] != small[small_offset++] ||
              big[big_offset++] != small[small_offset++] ||
              big[big_offset++] != small[small_offset++] ||
              big[big_offset] != small[small_offset]
            ) {
              result = false;
              break;
            }
          }
          if (result) return callback(true,'Found at '+big_x+' '+big_y);
        }
      }
      return callback(false,'not found');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try paper.js

it allows you to use your image as a raster

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/using-pixel-colors/
http://paperjs.org/tutorials/images/working-with-rasters/

the paper.js lib can definitely do more than comparing images..

here's a simple script that works..

```
            // rasterize both images
        var im_a = new Raster('image_a');
        var im_b = new Raster('image_b');

        var ratio = Math.round(im_a.width / 100);

        // downsize the images so we don't have to loop through all the pixels.
        im_a.size = new Size(im_a.width/ratio, im_a.height/ratio);
        im_b.size = new Size(im_b.width/ratio, im_b.height/ratio);

        //hide the images, so they don't display on the canvas
        im_a.visible = false;
        im_b.visible = false;

        var different = false;

        // check the image dimensions

        if((im_a.width == im_b.width) && (im_a.height == im_b.height)){

            // loop through the pixels
            for(x = 0 ; x < im_a.width ; x++){
                for(y = 0; y < im_a.height; y++){
                    if(im_a.getPixel(x,y) != im_b.getPixel(x,y) ){
                        different = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


        }else{
            alert('not the same size');
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, i don't know if there's something out there for that so, i'll give it a shot:

first, you will need a function to compare two arrays, you will find one anywhere on the web; like:

```
function arrayCompare(){
   if (x === y)
      return true;            
   if (x.length != y.length)
      return false;
   for (key in x) {
      if (x[key] !== y[key]) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

then you create a function that will return the imageData, of the image:

```
function getImgData(imgUrl){
   var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
   img.src = '../img/logo.png'; // params are urls for the images
   var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = img.width;
   canvas.height = img.height;
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.drawImage(img1,0,0);
   var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
   //returns an array, see documentation for * info
   return imageData.data;
}
```

then you can do something like:

```
var imgData1 = getImgData('../img/image1');
var imgData2 = getImgData('../img/image2');

if(arrayCompare(imgData1, imgData2)){
   //images are the same;
} else {
   // images are different
}
```

Now, this covers the first part of the problem. I'm sure that with a little bit of effort, you can find a function on the web to compare 2 arrays finding out if one is contained by the other.

As a final note, i am aware that these arrays are very very large and that this implemention may not be cost effective. I know that there are probably better solutions for this problem, but this was what i could think of. I'm sure you can find more effective array comparers around and, maybe my approach is completely useless near others that i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

**[Resemble.js](http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/)** is a JavaScript library for image comparison. From GitHub description:

> Resemble.js can be used for any image analysis and comparison
>   requirement you might have in the browser. However, it has been
>   designed and built for use by the PhantomJS powered visual regression
>   library **PhantomCSS**. PhantomCSS needs to be able to ignore antialiasing
>   as this would cause differences between screenshots derived from
>   different machines.
>
> Resemble.js uses the HTML5 File API to parse image data, and canvas
>   for rendering image diffs.

Answer (score 0):

assuming data1 & data2 are arrays. you can use canvasPixelArray(s)

```
var same = [];
same = data1 && data2;
if (same.length < data1.length) {
   //your code here
}
```